# Prince of Persia: The Two Thrones not installing

Tags: technical-issues, prince-of-persia-the-two-thrones

I have been trying to install Prince Of Persia: The Two Thrones in my PC, but it's not installing.

I had used win-zip instead of MS Installer. After extracting all the files when I open the main file it shows the basic needs of the game. I found that my PC have all the basic needs but still its not running, it's only showing the basic needs while I open the main file.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it? Any idea where the main problem is?

Comment: Winzip?  Why are you unzipping files instead of installing off of the disc?

Comment: The installation is more than just the files; there are registry keys and prerequisites that come along with the game itself.  That would be why it's not working.

Comment: It's not asking for a key because that's part of the *installation* process.  Copying files doesn't catch everything, and when you try to run a game you've copied from another computer, most often it won't run because it's looking for stuff that you missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use the installer, so essential setup steps haven't been done. It's not enough to have the files in the right place – the installer has to perform final configuration of your system and those files so that the game will function.